# Error with addons_model being loaded

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor

I have found that when using the sample templates that come with the Exp-resso Store and Zoo Visitor add-ons on EE 2.7.2, I get the following PHP error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: EE::$typography
>
> Filename: core/EE_Output.php
>
> Line Number: 308
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function parse_type() on a non-object in [MYPATH_SYSTEM_PATH]/expressionengine/core/EE_Output.php on line 308

Commenting out line 308 of *that* file:

```
$data['content'] = $EE->typography->parse_type(stripslashes($data['content']), array('text_format' => 'xhtml'));
```

Then produces a handled error:

> The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: addons_model

The error is thrown from CodeIgniter's Loader on line 194:

```
if (isset($CI->$name))
{
    show_error('The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: '.$name);
}
```

Commenting *that* line out makes everything run fine.

I've searched for uses of addons_model and the only reference I can see to it are either in third party addons (neither of which are enabled and neither of which are Store or Visitor), or EE's core. Obviously I don't want to be hacking at the core of EE or CI but this seems like an EE bug to me.

Has anybody else seen this problem or have a resolution?

Comment: Which versions of Store and Zoo Visitor are you running? Have you tried re-uploading all EE/Store/ZV files in case anything is corrupt or missing? Also if you disable (individually) either Store or ZV, does the problem go away?

Comment: Is this happening on all the templates? Have you reduced code to narrow down what in the templates is triggering the error?

Comment: I have stripped Store's product.html template down to a single line: "{exp:channel:entries}{/exp:channel:entries}" and still the same error. So I think is EE, not Store. Will try Adrian's suggestion of restoring all core files

Comment: Found it. The LibrarEE module (1.0.6) was the culprit. An update to the latest 1.07 fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from @Adrian Macneil, I tried installing Store and ZV again. No luck, so with Store installed, started removing all OTHER add-ons and tracked it down to version 1.0.6 of LibrarEE. An update to 1.0.7 sorted it.